# Windows command prompt command to duplicate file?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm using cmd on Windows 10.

I'd like to copy file `day_template.md` to `day2.md`, `day3.md`, .., `dayN.md`

What is th command for creating multiple copies with this name pattern. I'd need some incrementor to make each day{i}.md, where i is specified by me.

Would also be good to check if file exists or not. For example, I've manually created `day1.md`

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Although bash and cmd.exe are both shells, the two have very little in common beyond that.  This is *not* a question about Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write those commands into `cmd.exe` command prompt

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, N) do (
    if not exist day%x.md (
        copy day_template.md day%x.md
    )
)
```

where `N` is the maximum number of copies of the file you want to make.
If you want to embed this code into a batch script, use `%%` in place of `%`, i.e.

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, N) do (
    if not exist day%%x.md (
        copy day_template.md day%%x.md
    )
)
```

Comment: The `cp` command is `copy` under cmd.exe. Also, in a .bat file, the `%` must be doubled.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.